# How to get a source package from an installed version?

Tags: r, package

I have installed a custom package (not from CRAN) but unfortunately I can't find the original `.tar.gz` any more. Is there a way to get it from the installed version I have in order to be able to put it on other machines ?

Comment: You can sometimes just copy the directory containing the package you want. Not sure if this always works.

Comment: my guess is that changing the OS will make this fail because binary pacakges are specified to it. But I may try yes !

Comment: do you mean that you want to recreate the exact `.tar.gz` from your installed version?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme exactly, or more precisely to be able to install it on other machine regardless of the OS. It can be binary package too.

Comment: I would bet that's hardly possible but I don't know enough of what happens during installation to accurately answer. Highly interested by the answer though!